# Google Classroom API -> Reset Meet-link

Tags: c#, api

I'm adding new teachers to the Google workspace using the admin-directory API and also add them to multiple classrooms using the Classroom-API.

**However** there is an (known) issue.
New teachers does not have host-rights so cannot start a Meet-session. The problem has nothing to do with permissions or groups.

**Google has a solution** : reset (manually) the Meet-link. This solution works, however unpractical when new teachers are administrated programmatically.

SO : Does anyone knows a way to reset a classroom Meet-link with an API-call ?
(and NO, Google's first-line could not help me).

I work in C#.
Thanks a lot for any useful contribution!

Comment: shouldn't you post that question to google?

Comment: I did, the case is upgraded to API-support now, and I'm waiting for a reply. Meanwhile ou teachers are a little stuck... :(